# GlassMapper Render Image with placeholder image

Tags: glass-mapper

If image field is null or empty `@RenderImage` does not render the `<img>` attribute.

Is there a way to tell GlassMapper's `@RenderImage` to use default placeholder image if no image exists or comes from sitecore?

Can we set this configuration sitewide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative would be a custom Data Mapper that replaces the standard SitecoreFieldImageMapper. You could then set a default image for every empty field.

However I think that a custom extension to GlassHtml, e.g RenderImageWithPlaceholder, would be a better solution.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible "out-of-the-box" as far as I am aware. And instead of creating a new version of the @RenderImage method to allow this, I would do this check in your model before you hand it over to your view. If you are using a controller rendering, I would do something like:

```
if (model.MyImage == null)
{
    model.MyImage = new Image()
    {
        Src = "/mydefaultImage.jpg", 
        Alt = string.Empty
    };
}
```

You could probably wrap your `SitecoreContext.GetItem<T>` and apply this to all Glass.Mapper.Sc.Fields.Image's in your model if you want to use the same default image in all of your models.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved this, for future reference:

Created an extension method for `Glass.Mapper.Sc.Fields.Image` which returns default image placeholder if image field is Null or empty.

```
    public static Image GetDefaultPlacholderImage(this Image image)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(image?.Src))
        {
            return new Image { Src = Core.Constants.Constants.PlaceholderImagePath, Alt = string.Empty };
        }
        return image;
    }
```

In cshtml:

```
@RenderImage(child, x => x.ListingDetailsImage.GetDefaultPlacholderImage())
```